# Pop OS: install multiple nvidia drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I'd like to configure a Windows VM in PopOS. I have 2 GPUs in my system, a GTX 1660 Super and a GTX 550 Ti.

The PopOS installation came with the nvidia 440 driver pre-installed, which made use of my 1660 Super with ease.

However, I see that this driver doesn't support my 550 Ti. Based on my research, the 390 version is the latest to support it, but it doesn't support the 1660 super yet. This means that I should install both of these drivers if I want to use both GPUs. Do i even need the 440 version driver, if all I want to use the 1660 Super for is the VM?

How can I do this?

Comment: update: tried downgrading to the 384 version which caused pop os to halt while booting